General Form of the Biot-Savart Law for anywhere on the $x$-Axis
This question is beyond me, and I have very little direction for solving it. I understand that the component of $\ B $ perpendicular to the $x$-axis is 0, and that the component parallel along the $x$-axis is doubled, which is where I assume the 2 on the denominator comes from.
I can't find anything in my lecture notes/online describing a general formula for the Biot-Savart Law for any point on the x-axis. Anyone have any ideas?

Here is diagram 4)b) mentioned in the question:


Is the definition not in the text used in your class (if you have one)?

The $\bf B$ field on the axis a distance $\bf d$ above a loop is given by
\begin{eqnarray}
{\bf B(d)} & = & \frac{I}{c}\oint 
\frac{[{\bf dr'}\times{\bf (r-r')}]}{|{\bf r-r'}|^3}\nonumber\\
& = &\frac{I}{c}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{a^2d\theta{\bf\hat d}}{(a^2+d^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}}
\nonumber\\
& = &\frac{2\pi I a^2{\bf\hat d}}{c(a^2+d^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}}.
\label{bloop}
\end{eqnarray}
(In Gaussian units.)
